# Redux framework somehow added to my site, can't locate in plugins

Tags: plugins, security

I've been working on a site for over a year and just now notice Redux Framework is somehow on the site. Noticed it when I went to Tools > Backup and saw it was in Tools.  Clicked on it and saw the whole What's New page along with other tabs talking about it.  I have been the only person to install anything or to upgrade in at least 6 months.  Site owner confirms this.

Went to plugins to see Redux Framework and don't see it installed.  Checked my theme's function file and don't see it being called up.

The same theme has been in effect for at least 6 months (I switched it out to do troubleshooting only).

How do I locate where this is?  And does the existence of this framework mean that the site has been hacked somehow?

Comment: Can you show the image what you see?

Comment: Check it out here: [link]https://postimg.org/image/x1bwu78zj/

Answer (score 0):

Redux Framework can enter the WordPress world via the plugin or via the theme. If you can search Your project from some editor like the Sublime or Atom starting from the WordPress root folder.

The search term should be "redux". Just let us know what You get, and you may also answer your question.

Comment: I've got (unbelievably) dialup internet here so what I usually do won't work...download the entire folder and use Atom to search.  Can I search directly on the ftp client (I'm using fetch but could use something else like Transmit)?

Comment: Uh, dial-up Internet! I am instantly 20 years younger!